Budget & Checkbook Ledger - Balance Forward
This is what I have.  Two Tables:
Income Table



PayDate
Amount




1/1/2025
2650.00


1/10/2025
3050.00



Transaction Table



Date
Amount
AssignedPayDay




1/1/2025
38.52
1/1/2025


1/1/2025
200.00
1/1/2025


1/3/2025
1625.00
1/1/2025


1/5/2025
428.00
1/1/2025


1/10/2025
415.00
1/10/2025


1/11/2025
151.25
1/10/2025



So the "Paydate" from the Income Table is the join to the Transaction Table as all expense transactions are assigned to a a "PayDate" in the income Table via the Transaction table "AssignedPayDay" field.
What I am trying to do is get query that will total all the transactions for each pay day, subtract them and carry forward to the next payday any balance.
I was able to make a query that totals the transactions per assigned payday and subtracts them to get the balance for that payday but I can't figure out how to carry the balance remaining to the next payday.  I used this code:
Select i.PayDate, i.Amount
,SUM(t.Amount) as TotalTrans
,(i.Amount - sum(t.Amount)) as Balance
From Income i
LEFT JOIN Transactions t on t.AssignedPayDay = i.PayDate
Group by Paydate, i.Amount
ORDER BY PayDate

And it returns this:



PayDate
Amount
TotalTrans
Balance




1/1/2025
2650.00
2291.52
358.48


1/10/2025
3050.00
566.25
2483.75



What I can't figure out is how to carry the Balance forward to get this:



PayDate
Amount
TotalTrans
Balance




1/1/2025
2650.00
2291.52
358.48


1/10/2025
3050.00
566.25
2842.23



( 3050.00 + Bal forward of 358.48  - 566.25 = 2842.23 )
NOTE: Of course there are more rows in each table.

use SUM with OVER(). SUM(i.Amount - SUM(t.Amount)) over (order by i.PayDate) as Balance

Wow that worked!! Thanks, that was fast!

No just joined today?

Taking the tour would you explain it all

To perform recursive function you can use Common Table Expression. This can help you carry forward your balance so that you can calculate a cumulative balance.
I tried your example in db-fiddle with below query and using PostgreSQL.
CREATE TABLE Income (
    PayDate DATE PRIMARY KEY,
    Amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Transactions (
    Date DATE NOT NULL,
    Amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    AssignedPayDay DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (AssignedPayDay) REFERENCES Income(PayDate)
);

INSERT INTO Income (PayDate, Amount) VALUES 
('2025-01-01', 2650.00),
('2025-01-10', 3050.00);


INSERT INTO Transactions (Date, Amount, AssignedPayDay) VALUES 
('2025-01-01', 38.52, '2025-01-01'),
('2025-01-01', 200.00, '2025-01-01'),
('2025-01-03', 1625.00, '2025-01-01'),
('2025-01-05', 428.00, '2025-01-01'),
('2025-01-10', 415.00, '2025-01-10'),
('2025-01-11', 151.25, '2025-01-10');

-- TEST DATA
SELECT * FROM Income;
SELECT * FROM Transactions;


-- CTE 
WITH RECURSIVE BalanceCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        i.PayDate, 
        i.Amount,
        SUM(t.Amount) AS TotalTrans,
        (i.Amount - SUM(t.Amount)) AS Balance
    FROM 
        Income i
    LEFT JOIN 
        Transactions t ON t.AssignedPayDay = i.PayDate
    GROUP BY 
        i.PayDate, i.Amount
    ORDER BY 
        i.PayDate
),
RunningTotalCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        PayDate,
        Amount,
        TotalTrans,
        Balance,
        Balance AS RunningBalance
    FROM 
        BalanceCTE
    WHERE 
        PayDate = (SELECT MIN(PayDate) FROM BalanceCTE)
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        b.PayDate,
        b.Amount,
        b.TotalTrans,
        b.Balance,
        (b.Amount + rt.RunningBalance - b.TotalTrans) AS RunningBalance
    FROM 
        BalanceCTE b
    JOIN 
        RunningTotalCTE rt ON rt.PayDate = (
            SELECT MAX(PayDate) 
            FROM BalanceCTE 
            WHERE PayDate < b.PayDate
        )
)

SELECT 
    PayDate,
    Amount,
    TotalTrans,
    RunningBalance AS Balance
FROM 
    RunningTotalCTE
ORDER BY 
    PayDate;




Thank you and also for the DB Fiddle link.

You could use analytic functions with windowing clause to get the expected result  ...
--      Sample    Data:  
CREATE TABLE Income ( PayDate DATE PRIMARY KEY, Amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO Income (PayDate, Amount) VALUES 
  ('2025-01-01', 2650.00),
  ('2025-01-10', 3050.00);

CREATE TABLE Transactions ( a_Date DATE NOT NULL, Amount DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
                            AssignedPayDay DATE NOT NULL, 
                            FOREIGN KEY (AssignedPayDay) 
                            REFERENCES Income(PayDate) );
INSERT INTO Transactions (a_Date, Amount, AssignedPayDay) VALUES 
  ('2025-01-01', 38.52, '2025-01-01'),
  ('2025-01-01', 200.00, '2025-01-01'),
  ('2025-01-03', 1625.00, '2025-01-01'),
  ('2025-01-05', 428.00, '2025-01-01'),
  ('2025-01-10', 415.00, '2025-01-10'),
  ('2025-01-11', 151.25, '2025-01-10');

--      SQL:  
Select       PayDate,
             Coalesce( Sum(Income - Coalesce(Outcome, 0)) 
                           Over(Order By PayDate 
                           Rows Between Unbounded Preceding 
                                        And 1 Preceding), 0 ) as OpeningAmount, -- you can omit this column if you don't need it in the resultset
             Income, Outcome, 
             --
             Coalesce( Sum(Income - Coalesce(Outcome, 0)) 
                           Over(Order By PayDate 
                           Rows Between Unbounded Preceding 
                                        And 1 Preceding), 0 ) + Income - Outcome as Balance
From         ( Select     i.PayDate, Max(i.Amount) as Income, Sum(t.Amount) as Outcome
               From       Income i
               Left Join  Transactions t ON( t.AssignedPayDay = i.PayDate )
               Group By   i.PayDate
            ) g
Order By    PayDate;

Result:



PayDate
OpeningAmount
Income
Outcome
Balance




2025-01-01
0.00
2650.00
2291.52
358.48


2025-01-10
358.48
3050.00
566.25
2842.23



fiddle
